# How to run scenarios of a feature file instead of feature files using testng

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I have the testng file as below

```
<test thread-count="5" name="Test" parallel="classes">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.cucumber.runners.smoketestcasesRunner1" /> 
        <class name="com.cucumber.runners.HRSmokeTestCasesRunner2" />            
    </classes>
</test>
```

and the runner file is as below

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;

@CucumberOptions(features = "smoketestcases.feature",glue = "com.cucumber.steps")

public class smoketestcasesRunner1 {
@Test
public void runCukes() {

    new TestNGCucumberRunner(getClass()).runCukes();

}

}
```

which will run the feature files in parallel.  But i want to run the scenarios in parallel using testng not the feature files how to achieve it using testng

Comment: What IDE are you using? I use intellij and can launch everythings seperately and everything all together. I can also filter usings arguments in combination with annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you upgrade to the latest version of Cucumber.

Quoting the official documentation

> Add a cucumber runner by extending the `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`
>   class and overriding the scenarios method in the parallel package
>   (same name as step definition package) in `src/test/java` folder. Set
>   the parallel option value to true for the `DataProvider` annotation.

```java
package parallel;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

public class RunCucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

Read more from the documentation [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/#testng)